# dict.items() in python dictionary return type

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code to print items from a dictionary.

```
   my_dict = {
              "apples": 430,
              "bananas": 312,
              "oranges": 525,
              "pears": 217,
              "strawberries": 267,
              "blueberry": 179,
              "boysenberry": 432,
              "blackberry": 266,
              "apricot": 321,
              "plum": 143,
              "peaches": 154
            }

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    print('key {} value {}\n'.format(k, v))
```

The above code works fine and prints the key and the values. Just out of curiosity I wanted to try

```
k,v = my_dict.items()
```

it gives me an error.I want to know why this is ? My understanding is that `my_dict.items()` returns `k and v`

Comment: `.items()` gives you an *iterable* of key-value pairs - unless you have precisely two keys, that assignment is bound to fail.

Comment: Why not try `for object in my_dict.items(): print(object)` first to get a better idea about what you're iterating over?

Answer (score 4):

It returns a list of items (in python3 `dict_items` object), that you cannot assign them to two variable. If you want to separately get the keys and values you can use `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` attributes:

```
>>> my_dict.items()
[('bananas', 312), ('oranges', 525), ('peaches', 154), ('strawberries', 267), ('boysenberry', 432), ('apricot', 321), ('plum', 143), ('pears', 217), ('apples', 430), ('blueberry', 179), ('blackberry', 266)]
>>> 
>>> k, v = my_dict.keys(), my_dict.values()
>>> 
>>> k
['bananas', 'oranges', 'peaches', 'strawberries', 'boysenberry', 'apricot', 'plum', 'pears', 'apples', 'blueberry', 'blackberry']
>>> 
>>> v
[312, 525, 154, 267, 432, 321, 143, 217, 430, 179, 266]
```

Comment: *cough* Python 3 *cough*